# Dynamic conversion from integer value to type (C++11 template metaprogramming?)

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am trying to reduce code duplication through templates. I already moved most code to this helper `iterate_function_from_CSC_helper` which is now a template. However, this function still repeats a lot of code just to call a different specialization of a template:

```cpp
std::function<std::pair<int, double>(int idx)>
IterateFunctionFromCSC(const void* col_ptr, int col_ptr_type, const int32_t* indices, const void* data, int data_type, int64_t ncol_ptr, int64_t , int col_idx) {
  CHECK(col_idx < ncol_ptr && col_idx >= 0);
  if (data_type == C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT32) {
    if (col_ptr_type == C_API_DTYPE_INT32) {
      return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<float, int32_t>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);
    } else if (col_ptr_type == C_API_DTYPE_INT64) {
      return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<float, int64_t>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);
    }    
  } else if (data_type == C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT64) {
    if (col_ptr_type == C_API_DTYPE_INT32) {
      return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<double, int32_t>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);
    } else if (col_ptr_type == C_API_DTYPE_INT64) {
      return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<double, int64_t>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);
    }
  }
  Log::Fatal("Unknown data type in CSC matrix");
  return nullptr;
}
```

I'd like to automatically map the integers `data_type` and `col_ptr_dtype` which are received at runtime to the types float/double and int32_t/int64_t respectively and calling the template with those. Something like this:

```cpp
std::function<std::pair<int, double>(int idx)>
IterateFunctionFromCSC(const void* col_ptr, int col_ptr_type, const int32_t* indices, const void* data, int data_type, int64_t ncol_ptr, int64_t , int col_idx) {
  CHECK(col_idx < ncol_ptr && col_idx >= 0);

  if (<TTag<data_col>::invalid_type || TTag<col_ptr_type>::invalid_type) {
    Log::Fatal("Unknown data type in CSC matrix");
    return nullptr;
  }

  return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<TTag<data_type>::type, TTag<col_ptr_type>::type>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);

}
```

Is that possible? I assumed with some metaprogramming one could eliminate this.

I tried the following but cannot make `dummy_IterateFunctionFromCSC` consume a non const input (which will be the case at runtime):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


#define C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT32 (0)  /*!< \brief float32 (single precision float). */
#define C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT64 (1)  /*!< \brief float64 (double precision float). */
#define C_API_DTYPE_INT32   (2)  /*!< \brief int32. */
#define C_API_DTYPE_INT64   (3)  /*!< \brief int64. */



struct TTagInvalidType {}; //! Meant for invalid types in TTag.

template <int C_API_DTYPE>
struct TTag {
  using type = TTagInvalidType;  
};

template<>
struct TTag<C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT32> {
  using type = float;
};

template <>
struct TTag<C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT64> {
  using type = double;
};

template <>
struct TTag<C_API_DTYPE_INT32> {
  using type = int32_t;
};

template <>
struct TTag<C_API_DTYPE_INT64> {
  using type = int64_t;
};



template <typename T>
void example_f () {
    T x = 3.6;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}

template <>
void example_f<TTagInvalidType>() {    
    std::cout << "Abort!\n";
}

template<int x>
void dummy_IterateFunctionFromCSC() {
    f<typename TTag<x>::type>();
}

int main() {
    const int m = 2;  // Doesn't work for non const integers (true at runtime)
    dummy_IterateFunctionFromCSC<m>();
}
```

This compiles but only with constant m, not with an integer received from the user for instance.

Is this impossible because the type-dispatching must be computed at compile time? Or is it possible and how? :D

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you want template instantiations depending on run-time values? Did I understand that correctly? If so, you can't.

Comment: There's a finite and very small set of types in our template function (4): int,float,long,double.
I'm looking to convert 2 integers at runtime to 2 types to specialize my template function call `iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<type1, type2>(args...)` as we expose `IterateFunctionFromCSC` in the API for the user (that is our entry point).

This is what you mean by template instantiation? And that it is impossible?

Comment: Non-type parameters, like `m` in `dummy_IterateFunctionFromCSC<m>()` need to be `constexpr`, so `if(m == 2) dummy_IterateFunctionFromCSC<2>();` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning runtime value to compile time value requires indeed some if/switch like you did.

You might avoid some duplication by additional split:

C++17 might help reduce verbosity with `std::variant`, some utilities:

```
template <typename T> struct type_identity { using type = T; };

// type should be an enum
std::variant<type_identity<int32_t>, type_identity<int64_t>> to_compile_int_type(int type)
{
    switch (type) {
        case C_API_DTYPE_INT32: return type_identity<int32_t>{};
        case C_API_DTYPE_INT64: return type_identity<int64_t>{};
        default:
            Log::Fatal("Unknown int data type");
            throw "unknown type";
    }
}

// type should be an enum
std::variant<type_identity<float>, type_identity<double>> to_compile_float_type(int type)
{
    switch (type) {
        case C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT32: return type_identity<float>{};
        case C_API_DTYPE_FLOAT64: return type_identity<double>{};
        default:
            Log::Fatal("Unknown float data type");
            throw "unknown type";
    }
}
```

And then

```
std::function<std::pair<int, double>(int idx)>
IterateFunctionFromCSC(const void* col_ptr,
                       int col_ptr_type,
                       const int32_t* indices,
                       const void* data,
                       int data_type,
                       int64_t ncol_ptr,
                       int64_t ,
                       int col_idx)
{
    CHECK(col_idx < ncol_ptr && col_idx >= 0);
    std::visit(
        [&](auto intvar, auto floatvar){
            using inttype = typename decltype(intvar)::type;
            using floattype = typename decltype(floatvar)::type;

            return iterate_function_from_CSC_helper<floatype, inttype>(col_ptr, indices, data, col_idx);
        },
        to_compile_int_type(col_ptr_type),
        to_compile_float_type(data_type)
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm limited to c++11, is this possible in it as well with some alternative to variant?

Comment: @Alberto there's [`boost::variant`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/variant.html). In fact most new C++ standard functions begin their life from boost, so just check the boost equivalent

Comment: @phuclv: and **generic** lambda has to be written the old way too :(

Comment: another alternative: https://github.com/mpark/variant